# Show that there is no metric on $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ with $K\leq -1$ everywhere.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I try to solve this problem:

> Show that there is no metric on $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ with $K\leq -1$ everywhere.

Here, the *metric* on a domain $U$ is a $C^2$ function $\rho: U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ which vanishes only at isolated points.

And a curvature of $\rho$ is defined as follows
$$K=-\frac{1}{\rho^2}\Delta\log \rho$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator.

---

My try:

I want to apply Ahlfor's lemma and lead some contradiction.
According to Ahlfor's lemma, let $\rho$ be a metric in a domain $U$ with $K_{\rho}\leq -1$ when defined. Then $$\rho\leq \lambda_{\mathbb{D}},$$ where $ \lambda_{\mathbb{D}}$ is the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{D}$ is given by 
$$ \lambda_{\mathbb{D}}=\frac{2}{1-|z|^2}.$$
Then I got stuck... I don't know if I could get some contradiction in this way since $\rho\leq \lambda_{\mathbb{D}}$ is not like restriction that all metrics on $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ cannot satisfy.

Comment: To invoke Ahlfors' Lemma, you need a mapping $f\colon \Bbb D\to \Bbb C^*$. Otherwise your inequality "$\rho\le\lambda_{\Bbb D}$" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The domain $\mathbb{C}^*$ can be smoothly embedded in the unit disc, which admits a hyperbolic metric. Hence, so does $\mathbb{C}^*$.